# $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{(1/x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am doing it like, $\lim_{x \to 0}    ((1+x)^{1/x})^{(1/x)}
=\lim_{x \to 0}    e^{(1/x)}$

So my question is can we do this.
As what I know from algebra of limit that if 
$\lim_{x \to a}   f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exist then 
$\lim_{x \to a}  f(x)^{g(x)} 
= (\lim_{x \to a} f(x) )^{(\lim_{x \to a} g(x))}$

But as I am doing the question $\lim_{x \to 0} 1/x$ is D.N.E so this rule is failing. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong or my understanding is not correct.

And what should be the correct method to attack this question.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

If it exists then

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( 1+x \right)^\frac1{x^2} = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2} \right)$$

Use [L'hopital rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

You might want to work with $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$ separately and check if they are equal.

Remark:

For your first approach, nope, we can't evaluate the limit at the base first and then evaluate the limit at the power later.

For your second approach, you have reached something called [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: The fact that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2}$ doesn't exist is a bit of an issue, though.

Comment: Good point! I miss that actually. Thanks.